# Definite integrals involving exp and Bessel functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I want to know closed-form of following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{R} e^{-icx} x^{n} J_{n-1} (ax) dx
$$
where $J_{n}$ is the Bessel function of the first kind and order $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This equation is similar to [Hankel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform) of exp, but it's difficult for me to calculate.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: There is some advantage to consider it instead as the Fourier transform of $C(x)x^n J_{n-1}(ax)$ where $C$ is the characteristic function of interval $(0,R)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot! I'll try it. I found the Fourier transform of $J_{0}$, but is the Fourier transform for general $J_{n}$ known? If you know, please let me know the references.

Comment: Some information in the answers there : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2129589

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks Thank you.

Comment: I advise you to download Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 'Table of integrals" that you can find online [here](https://archive.org/details/GradshteinI.S.RyzhikI.M.TablesOfIntegralsSeriesAndProducts/page/n741/mode/2up) and look at formulas around page 747 in my own paper edition.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your kind! I found 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-icx} x^{n+1} J_{n}(ax) dx = \frac{2^{n+1} ca^{n} \Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi} (c^{2}+a^{2})^{n+\frac{3}{2}}}
$$ 
from the description on [p732 7,8](https://archive.org/details/GradshteinI.S.RyzhikI.M.TablesOfIntegralsSeriesAndProducts/page/n779/mode/2up).
This is exactly infinite version of the problem I want to know.
However I haven't found finite interval version yet. I will continue to think about it.

Comment: Happy you have found your way in this garden of formulas! The "non infinite" upper bound case can be without any closed-form formula...